# Python - Getting the first child of the parent element with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, parent-child

I have the following HTML:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr role="row">
        <td>abc1</td>
        <td>abc2</td>
        <td>abc3</td>
        <td class="hm">Data1</td>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td class="hm">no</td>
        <td class="hx">yes</td>
        <td class="hm">Updated</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
        <td>def1</td>
        <td>def2</td>
        <td>def3</td>
        <td class="hm">Data3</td>
        <td>Data4</td>
        <td class="hm">no</td>
        <td class="hx">no</td>
        <td class="hm">Updated</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
        <td>hij1</td>
        <td>hij2</td>
        <td>hij3</td>
        <td class="hm">Data5</td>
        <td>Data6</td>
        <td class="hm">no</td>
        <td class="hx">no</td>
        <td class="hm">Updated</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
        <td>klm1</td>
        <td>klm2</td>
        <td>klm3</td>
        <td class="hm">Data7</td>
        <td>Data8</td>
        <td class="hm">no</td>
        <td class="hx">yes</td>
        <td class="hm">Updated</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There are multiples of these `<tr>` tags so I am doing the following to find one where there is a child `<td>` tag with `class="hx"` and a text of `yes`:

```
if (Soup.find('table', {'id' : 'mytable'}).find('td', text='yes', attrs={'class' : 'hx'})):
    print "Found 'yes'"
```

But I am interested in the first `<td>` tag in the `<tr>` that is found. I tried doing the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
print Soup.find('table', {'id' : 'mytable'}).find('td', text='yes', attrs={'class' : 'hx'}).parent.find('td')[0].text
```

Alternatively, the following works but it seems like a really drawn out way of doing this, especially if I am not sure how many `<td>` tags will be present between the two:

```
print Soup.find('table', {'id' : 'mytable'}).find('td', text='yes', attrs={'class' : 'hx'}).previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.text
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Am I missing something?

Comment: so you want `Col1` to be printed at the end?

Comment: Correct, so the second `print` with all of the `.previousSibling`'s works, but as stated, I am not sure how many other `<td>` tags will be between the one I find and the first one.

Comment: Sure, I just updated it, but note that I want the first instance of `find('td', text='yes', attrs={'class' : 'hx'})`. So only `abc1` should be printed here, not `abc1` and `klm1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second print change:

```
find('td')[0]
```

to:

```
find('td')
```

Find returns the first element, so no need to index.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """
<html><head><title>Foo</title></head>
<body>
<table id="mytable">
<tr role="row">
    <td>Col1</td>
    <td>Col2</td>
    <td>Col3</td>
    <td class="hm">Data1</td>
    <td>Data2</td>
    <td class="hm">no</td>
    <td class="hx">yes</td>
    <td class="hm">Updated</td>
</tr>
<table>
"""
Soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

# Will raise error
# print Soup.find('table', {'id' : 'mytable'}).find('td', text='yes', attrs={'class' : 'hx'}).find_parent().find('td')[0].text

print Soup.find('table', {'id' : 'mytable'}).find('td', text='yes', attrs={'class' : 'hx'}).find_parent().find('td').text
```

**Edit**

To get the second column change `find('td')` to `find_all('td')`. This will return a list, so you can do:

```
td_data = Soup.find('table', {'id' : 'mytable'}).find('td', text='yes', attrs={'class' : 'hx'}).find_parent().find_all('td')
print td_data[0].text # 1st column
print td_data[1].text # 2nd column
```

Obviously, if you index greater than `len(td_data) - 1` it will throw an `IndexError`

Comment: what about getting the second column then? Say, I need both `abc1` and `abc2`. EDIT: doing `find('td').nextSibling` seems to do the trick for `abc2`

Comment: See my edit, by changing to `find_all` you can now index each column

Comment: Sorry, I got the code the wrong way round in my example before the edit, but now it's fixed

Comment: Understood. This seems to work just fine and is a viable workaround. Thanks!